# The standard deviation is more stable than the mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, means

In an introduction to the subject of hypothesis testing, a book on probability and statistics for engineering students has a statement asserting that "the standard deviation is more stable than the mean' (paraphrased). The context is paraphrased as follows:

> A machine packs packages of powered sugar. If the machine works properly, then the weight of each package is normally distributed with a mean 0.5kg and a standard deviation 0.015kg. One day, a worker randomly selected 9 bags of powered sugar packed by the machine, with the following weights:
>
> `0.497kg, 0.506kg, 0.518kg, 0.524kg, 0.498kg, 0.511kg, 0.520kg, 0.515kg, 0.512kg`
>
> Use this to decide whether the machine was working properly.

In order the derive a solution, the books does the following (still paraphrased):

> Let the random variable $X$ denote the weight of a package of powered sugar on this particular day, and let $\mu$ and $\sigma$ denote the mean and the standard deviation of $X$ respectively. Experience suggests that the standard deviation is more stable than the mean. So we may suppose that $\sigma=0.015$. Thus $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, 0.015^2)$, with $\mu$ unknown. With this in mind, we propose two hypotheses:
> $$H_0: \mu = 0.5, \qquad H_1: \mu\neq 0.5.$$
> We want to use the data available to decide which one to accept.

The book then proceeds to introduce the statistic
$$ \frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$$
to do the hypothesis testing.

The questionable assumption about the standard deviation being equal to 0.015 aside, I want to know **whether it is true that 'experience suggests that the standard deviation is more stable than the mean'. And if this is true, do we have a theoretical explanation?**

I was thinking that perhaps we could interpret it this way: Denote the weight of a package produced by the machine when it is working properly by the random variable $Y$, then $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(\lambda, \theta^2)$, for some $\lambda$ and $\theta>0$. Then taking all possible factors into account, maybe we could view the weight of a package produced by the machine in each possible state (broken or not) as a new variable $Y_i\sim \mathcal{N}(\lambda, \theta^2)$, with all the $Y_i$ independent and indentically distributed. Then the statement is saying that for an $n$ large enough
$$ D(\bar{Y}) \geq D(S), \tag{1}$$
where $\bar{Y}$ is the sample mean $\bar{Y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$, and $S$ is the sample standard deviation, with $S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$. But it is not very difficult to see that Inequality $(1)$ is not always true. Failing to find any reference about this statement, I ask for your help!

Comment: When it says "by experience" it means empirically. There is no theoretical backing to this assumption and this is a paraphrase to "you may assume that standard deviation is fixed", implying $\sigma$ is not considered random and so not a subject of hypothesis test

Comment: @user340297:Thank you very much for your comment. I understood what the book was trying to do. However, I wasn't entirely sure if it is unlike the scenario with the statement "empirically the relative frequency converges to a certain number". Even if there is no theretical backing, do you know anywhere else this statement is mentioned?

Comment: I think the statement "empirically the relative frequency ~" might have some theoretical backing, since strong law of large numbers/CLT gives this result provided you have suffciently large number of trials.

Comment: @user340297: That is exactly why I mentioned it, to suggest that the original statement about the stability of standard deviation might also have some theoretical explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should interpret the statement *Experience suggests that the standard deviation is more stable than the mean* as the assertion that even when the machine is not working properly, the standard deviation of a package weight remains unchanged. Judging from the context, it's a statement about the population $\sigma$, not the sample standard deviation. So the author is trying to justify the continued use of $\sigma = 0.015$ no matter what the value of $\mu$ is. It seems unnecessary to even make this remark (since the hypothesis test is conducted under the assumption that the machine is working properly) unless there is a later exercise in computing the power of the test, where you need to consider the distribution of the test statistic when $\mu\ne0.5$.

If the statement is interpreted as a assertion about the stability of the *sample* standard deviation compared to that of the *sample* mean, you can show that for the normal distribution, **asymptotically the sample SD has half the variance of the sample mean**. For an IID sample from any distribution the variance of the sample mean is
$$
\frac{\sigma^2}n.\tag1$$ Less commonly known is the variance of the sample standard deviation. For the normal distribution it [turns out to be](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28033)
$$
\sigma^2\left[ 1 - \frac2{n-1}\left(\frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}2)}\right)^2\right],\tag2
$$
which behaves like $\sigma^2\over 2n$ as $n\to\infty$ [see Section 3 of [this paper](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~fessler/papers/files/tr/stderr.pdf)].

When $n=9$ formula (1) evaluates to $0.11\sigma^2$ while (2) is [approximately](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-(Gamma(4.5)%2FGamma(4))%5E2%2F4) $0.06\sigma^2$. Nonetheless, this fact should *not* be interpreted as justification for using the sample SD in place of the population SD, and notice that the example does not do so.